# Centering a wrapper DIV horizontally not working in Android

Tags: android, html, css

I'm working on a project for a client and ran into an issue when testing the website on my Android device. Basically, I just want to center a DIV which wraps around most of the body content.

```
<img src="images/lightingOverlay.png" style="z-index: 1000; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; top: 0;" />
<div style="border: solid 5px black; height: 50px; width: 978px; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; top: 100px;" >
  wrapped content!
</div>
```

I used inline styles for now. Even though the div and the image are using identical code, when viewing on the default Android browser, the image gets centered and the DIV doesn't.

I tried using a left: 50% positioning with negative margin equal to half the elements width as well, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Anyway, I've basically been playing with the code and testing it in Chrome v21 and Android for the last 2 days trying to figure out what the problems...and as you can see in the example, I've stripped down to the simplest elements without any luck. Anyone have any idea how I can get the horizontal centering to work in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, centering works now after using

```
style="width: 1200px; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; top: 0;"
```

The 1200px width here is the width of the large image overlay I'm using on the page, which also happens to the widest object on the page. It seems like the mobile browser takes the width of the widest element on the screen, and scales it so that this width is equal to the screen width. Then it does the rest of the rendering. If the screen is re-sized after that, apparently it doesn't bother re-positioning things?

Okay, so I'm not sure why this worked...just that it did. Hopefully it can help someone else who runs into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the position absolute, left, top & right bits of code you should be fine.

The DIV should only need margin:0 auto in order to be centered.

Comment: Well, I took out those pieces of code, and it still displays fine in Chrome. But when I get to the Android browser, it's still not centered.

Comment: The width of your DIV (including its borders) is 988px. What resolution is the android browser you're viewing the page in? Also, is the DIV sitting to the left or the right rather than being centered?

Comment: I'm not sure about the resolution of the browser, but the div is aligned left with a large margin on the right side. By the way, I tried aligning it to the right using absolute positioning, but the Android browser shows no change at all....almost like it's totally ignoring the positioning...

Comment: On your test page you have that DIV at the bottom containing analytics code. Is there any reason why that is in a div with positioning on it? Those script tags could simply sit in the HEAD of the page or just before the </body> tag on their own. (i.e. with no DIV tags round the <script> tags). That may be causing an issue.

Comment: That bottom section of your page has some HTML structure problems. E.G. you have code directly after the </body> tag. That won't work. ANd your code begins with a </noscript> tag. That's all sorts of broken. Fixing that will hopefully help.

Comment: Ah, that code seems to be added by the hosting service...but I've tested on Android from my local server as well without any success...

Comment: This should work, not sure what's going on if it doesn't I'm afraid: http://fiddle.jshell.net/SxH9k/

Comment: Still doesn't work when it comes to android...I guess I'll keep playing with the code and post if I find a solution...But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use absolute in this instance and rather use margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto;

```
<div style="border:solid 5px black; height:50px; width:978px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:100px;" >
  wrapped content!
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

you can also try this implementation

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
  <div style="border:solid 5px black; height:50px; width:978px; margin-top:100px;" >
    wrapped content!
  </div>
</div>
```

>

Comment: I just tried it by setting the margin-left and margin-right to auto using the shorthand `margin: 100px auto 0 auto;` property. It's still working in Chrome, but still no luck in Android. Also, the main reason I used the absolute positioning was because there are a large number of elements inside the wrapper using relative and absolute positioning, so I need these to behave appropriately as well...

Comment: what browser are you using on your android device?

Comment: I'm using the default browser that comes with Android. Btw, I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YsWJ6/7/) with the code thats causing issues.

Comment: strange, the margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; shows perfectly center on my android tablets stock browser :| http://jsfiddle.net/YsWJ6/28/

Comment: Weird, that code displays correctly on my Android as well...I guess maybe it's the huge image up top that's causing problems in my case. Anyway, I fixed it for now by styling the body...Appreciate your help though :D